# Wobbly newel post

Tags: trim-carpentry

This stair rail is wobbly, and I can't find information on repairing this type of installation. I suspect that the post is secured by a long screw, but the construction method appears to be different than other newel posts I've seen on DIY websites.[image]

Comment: Can you provide us photos of what's going on?

Comment: That's a tough situation. You have a lightweight railing, and that post barely qualifies as a newel. Even if rigidly mounted it's going to flex a bit.

Comment: isherwood is right.  That's more of an oversized baluster than a newel post.  If replacing it with something heftier isn't an option, you might be able to get by with rigging up some sort of base for it that would hold it in place and keep the flexing down, if not necessarily eliminate it.

Comment: @P.T.Curran my thoughts exactly.  Box in the base with something hefty and sturdy.  If you do have access from underneath via the basement, then you might have a few more options.